# What is the purpose of the function keyword in println

Tags: function

What is the purpose of the "function" in the following:

out.println("       function ecedigsDir()");

Answer (score 0):

There is no purpose. From what you have provided, the output would literally be:

```
 function ecedigsDir()
```

When you encase something in quotes, it will print out what is incased in them. (Maybe with the exception of printf).